# Automatically press the 'Next' button on a facts website

Tags: javascript

I've found a very informative website [Factslides](https://www.factslides.com/). On their front page, they have a slide of over 9,000 facts that you can read by clicking the next button.

I wanted to sit back and read the facts without pressing the next button, so I wrote the following code and placed it in the console:

```
var button=document.getElementById("nextA");
setInterval(function(){ 
button.click();
}, 12000);
```

Luckily, the code worked perfectly but I encountered a problem after 29 slides. After every 29 slides, the webpage refreshes itself and the code stops working.

After 29 slides, the URL of the web page changes to `https://www.factslides.com/p-2`

After 29 more slides it changes to `https://www.factslides.com/p-3`

And so on...

Please help me solving this problem so there's a continuous slide of facts without interruption.

Thank You!

Comment: If the page refreshes, your timer will be lost and I cannot see a way for you to get it back after reloading unless you paste your code again. Maybe you can do it with a browser extension?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because there is a javascript function that executes the `location.reload();` method every 348 seconds, or there could be an equiv-refresh tag, which looks like this:

```html
 <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"; URL="http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

There could also be a function redirecting to another page every 29 slides.

Comment: A comment from @defraggled points out that the website may only be storing 29 slides per hyperlink, meaning that the JS file does not persist when the URL is changed

To combat this, I would recommend using a macro software solution.

Answer (score 0):

The website simply only stores 29 "slides" per hyperlink. After 29, the 'next' button points to a new url, which contains the next set of "slides".

You won't be able to continue through these urls uninterrupted- at least, not with javascript alone. Javascript will not persist once you're at a new page.

I'd suggest exploring simple macro software solution. There are very lightweight and simple options depending on your OS.